# Change DOM element onscroll not working

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

Im trying to change my nav when a user scrolls 50px down on the page. In my consol log i can see that it detects the scroll, but it only shows 0, and not the new new amount.. What am i doing wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Scroll Test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
  window.onload = oppstart;

  function oppstart() {
   document.getElementById("doc").onscroll = scroll;
  }

  function scroll() {
   var element = document.getElementById("doc");
   var y = element.scrollTop;
   console.log(y);
   document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = y + " px";
   if (y === 50) {
    document.getElementById("navigation").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
  }

 </script>
 <style type="text/css">

  body {
   overflow: auto;
  }
  
  #navigation {
   height: 30vh;
   background-color: black;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  #main {
   height: 200vh;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body id="doc">
<nav id="navigation"></nav>
<div id="main">
<p id="utskrift"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
element.scrollTop;
```

to

```
window.scrollY
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Scroll Test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
  window.onload = oppstart;

  function oppstart() {
   document.getElementById("doc").onscroll = scroll;
  }

  function scroll() {
   var y = window.scrollY;
   console.log(y);
   document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = y + " px";
   if (y === 50) {
    document.getElementById("navigation").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
  }

 </script>
 <style type="text/css">

  body {
   overflow: auto;
  }
  
  #navigation {
   height: 30vh;
   background-color: black;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  #main {
   height: 200vh;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body id="doc">
<nav id="navigation"></nav>
<div id="main">
<p id="utskrift"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks :D